# What is the bash equivalent equivalent to the C shell `~/.cshrc` file?

Tags: bash, shell, csh

For several years I have grown accustomed to using the Bash Unix shell, which is the default on Macbooks.

I am running through some old software which directs me to make changes to the C-shell `~/.cshrc` file, which is read each time you begin a new csh or tcsh shell.

I'm not entirely sure what the Bash equivalent to this. I imagine I could simply `cd` to the appropriate subdirectory and make changes there.

Apologies for the ignorance.

Comment: You're probably looking for bashrc:

http://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file

Comment: @BrunoOliveira Perfect! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$HOME/.bashrc is the file you're looking for.

You can't open those files as /.xxxx because / is the root, not your $HOME

Type

```
cd $HOME;ls -la
```

to see what hidden files do you have in your $HOME directory

Comment: How do I access this file to make changes? I know which directory it is in by inputting `echo $HOME/.bashrc`, but I cannot open the file the usual way with VIM or Emacs, i.e. `vi /.bashrc`

Comment: Answer updated for more info

Comment: In the home directory, I use `sudo ls -la`. I see `.`, `..`, `.bash_history`, and `.bash_profile`. 
I don't see `.bashrc` or `.zschrc` unfortunately

Comment: Is it possible that this file doesn't exit, and that I should create it myself?

Comment: It appears Mac doesn't use the `.bashrc` file http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119711/why-mac-os-x-dont-source-bashrc

Comment: Why would you think that someone running on OS X would use ZShell… by default? What did I miss?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang It's not that OS X doesn't use the .bashrc file. It's that OS X Terminal.app gives you a _login_ shell by default, and that causes bash to read the .bash_profile. It may not matter for your particular purposes, but you can have a login shell that is not interactive, and vice-versa. You can get undesirable behavior putting contents in .bash_profile that is intended only for an interactive shell (with standard output/error connect to a tty or network pipe). You can simple do `[[ $- = *i* ]] && . ~/.bashrc` from your .bash_profile to source .bashrc in an interactive, login shell.

Comment: @kojiro For OS X users, what is the difference between `.profile` and `.bash_profile`? It seems I have Bash script installed in both

Comment: @ShanZhengYang if `.bash_profile` exists, bash invoked as a login shell will source it and ignore `.profile`. Otherwise, it will source `.profile`. If bash is invoked as `sh` instead of `bash`, it will source `.profile`. None of this behavior has anything in particular to do with OS X.